# Populate workbook containing many named ranges

Tags: vba, excel

I was working with workbooks which consisted of a large number of sheets with each sheet having only one named range containing a number of unlocked cells for user entry (there are some locked cells within the named ranges for restricted cells). I used to use the following code to populate these workbooks:

```
Sub LoopFillAuto()

Dim Nm As Name
CurrentValue = 0

For Each Nm In ActiveWorkbook.Names
     For Each myRange In Nm.RefersToRange.Cells
        If Not myRange.Locked Then
            myRange.Value = CurrentValue
            CurrentValue = CurrentValue + 1
        End If
    Next
Next

End Sub
```

The above would populate the sheets, and cells within the sheets, of the workbook IN SEQUENCE with all unlocked cells being given a value in increments of one (starting from zero) so that every unlocked cell in the workbook has a unique, and in order, value. The workbook could then be processed to generate output using an Excel addon. This made it very easy to check, by eye, if any output being generated by these workbooks had missing values as it would be easy to identify a missing number in the output sequence e.g. 1,2,3,5.

I am now having to use workbooks containing large numbers of named ranges with each sheet having hundreds of individual, unique and random named ranges which are not in any order throughout the workbook. When using the above to populate one of these new workbooks, every cell in the workbook will have a unique value but the values in the cells will not be in sequence making checking if there is missing output more difficult e.g. 214,6,586,85.

Is there a way to change the code so it will still populate the worksheets and cells in sequence, as it did with the older, more ordered workbooks?

Comment: Are the named ranges in a random order potentially on the sheets? You may be able to loop from left to right between each sheets active area, checking for unlocked cells - but it might be quite slow with 3 loops if you have a lot of sheets.

Comment: Hi Trum, thanks for the interest. Yes, the named ranges are in a random order within each sheet. Some sheets have well over a 1000 individual named ranges in random order. I will investigate your suggestion. Thank you